# Hibernate - Commit one item at a time within a list (ignoring the failed ones)

Tags: hibernate, commit

How can I commit one item at a time in hibernate. I have an arraylist of items. Need to save all of them to DB.. in case any records fail due to "being dirty".. m ok to ignore it and move on with other ones.

Tried committing the records in a loop as below

```
session.beginTran..

loop
{
  try
    {
      session.update(item)
      session.commit()
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { //log & ignore }
 }
```

This gave me "Nested Tran not possible" error..

Moved beginTran inside the loop.. But what m observing is.. If my first record fails, each commit tries to update the same record again even though {item} object gets next one from list, within the loop

```
loop
{
  try
    {
      session.beginTran
      session.update(item) //Eventhough item object gets loaded properly within the loop.. every time commit is executed, its trying to save the first failed record again.
      session.commit()
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { //log & ignore }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate exceptions are not recoverable. They leave the session in an inconsistent state, making further usage unreliable. As soon as an exception is thrown by the session, the session must be discarded.

Use a single session per transaction.

[Reference from the manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-exceptions):

> If the Session throws an exception, including any SQLException, immediately rollback the database transaction, call Session.close() and discard the Session instance. Certain methods of Session will not leave the session in a consistent state. No exception thrown by Hibernate can be treated as recoverable. Ensure that the Session will be closed by calling close() in a finally block.

Comment: Thanks JB.. Will try that..How much of a performance overhead to open and close session to loop through a record set of.. lets say 500..

Comment: Probably negligible. You can also try to use a single session, but you'll have to discard it as soon as an exception happens.